# Multiple user access database with Sql server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I have an access database that is stored on a network drive where all users access the one file. The database is linked to Sql server tables located in a local on site server. In my vba code my connection is to the access database.  My question is I know it's possible to just connect to sql server from vba but all my queries are stored in Access, so will my code be able to run the queries from access if it's connected to Sql server or would I need to re-write all the queries? The problem we are having is that more than one user may be on the same record pulled up and they are overwriting each other's changes. Also a user may need to take the program on their laptop instead of having to remote in to their desktop at office. I was thinking I could just give them a copy each and that would solve the problem. Does anyone have any answers?

Answer (score 0):

Just re-write the queries in SQL Server.  It may be painful now, but it shouldn't be too bad, and down the road a bit, you'll be glad you moved everything to SQL Server (much faster, more stable, you're using a real DB, etc.)

Answer (score -1):

You will want to pull all the queries into VBA and rewrite them with the appropriate parameters.

Comment: I am confused that you do not recommend the standard MS Access solution of having a separate front-end for each user.

Comment: @fionnuala this is what I was thinking but I would need to distribute copies when updates are made

Comment: If you connect to SQL Server via ODBC, your queries will most likely run "as is". There will be minor changes, and you may have to do some rewriting to optimize but that's another task. There's plenty of stuff on upgrading an Access backend to SQL Server if you browse for it.